# XQuery error: Filtering with variable returning empty result

Tags: xquery

I try to run the following XQuery:

```
let $d := doc("ferry.xml")
let $x := $d/ferry/trips/trip[@depart='08:00' and start='Stockholm']/captain[@crew]
return $d/ferry/crews/crew[@crewID=$x]/name
```

And get an empty result.

I would like to get the value in `<name>` where `<crew crewID="JI">` (=Jill).

I can see that `$x` includes `<captain crew="JI"/>` and when I run

`return $d/ferry/crews/crew[@crewID='JI']/name`

I get the expected result.

How can I make the return function read the variable correctly? Here is the XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ferry>
<ships>
    <ship shipID="SKHM">
        <name>Skeppsholm</name>
    </ship>
    <ship shipID="PERL">
        <name>Pearl</name>
        <cars>40</cars>
    </ship>
    <ship shipID="REVG">
        <name>Revenge></name>
        <length>50</length> 
    </ship>
</ships>
<crews>
    <crew crewID="JO">
        <name>Jack</name>
        <job>service</job>
        <job>deckhand</job>
    </crew>
    <crew crewID="JI">
        <name>Jill</name>
        <job>captain</job>
        <job>firstmate</job>
    </crew>
    <crew crewID="HA">
        <name>Harry</name>
        <job>deckhand</job> 
    </crew>
</crews>
<trips>
    <trip date="20171020" depart="08:00">
        <start>Stockholm</start>
        <end>Vaxholm</end> 
        <captain crew="JI" /> 
        <service crew="JO" /> 
    </trip>
    <trip date="20171130" depart="10:00">
        <start>Nacka</start>
        <end>Gustavberg</end> 
        <captain crew="JI" /> 
        <deckhand crew="HA" />
        <service crew="JA" /> 
    </trip>
</trips>
</ferry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
let $x := $d/ferry/trips/trip[@depart='08:00' and start='Stockholm']/captain[@crew]
```

to

```
let $x := $d/ferry/trips/trip[@depart='08:00' and start='Stockholm']/captain/@crew
```

You need `$x` to be just the value of the `crew` attribute; currently it returns the whole element `<captain crew="JI"/>`.